# EditText Loses Focus Second Time

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Edit Text , and after user click on button or on soft keyboard input , i do some action in background and restart this activity again . At first time the focus is on EditText , but after redirecting the focus is lost .

One more thing , I am using a bluetooth device to enter text in the EditText area .

In the starting of activity , i am getting the editText button and calling

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```

also after calling action , i am again requesting focus .

In manifest i am using :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

I have also tried to show keyboard always :

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(mLastNameET, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I have tried many things , please suggest how can i make it work ?

Comment: override onresume() and put this focus code in that method also.

Comment: onResume of activity ? can you provide code snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this,

First is to declare EditText.request focus() in on resume(), or second one is declare `<request focus />` tag between `<EditText>  <request focus/> <\EditText>`
You can also use this thing:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                editText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: overriding onResume does not work . What could be the reason

Comment: Update the answer , can try this also.

Comment: <EditText>   <requestFocus />  </EditText>

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it is fixed with adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in Manifest like below.
I hope it work for you too.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Some other developer might be able to help it. :(